# Strange wav files. What filter can I use?

Tags: java, audio, speech-recognition

I am working currently on a few projects connected with audio files recognition. However one type of files creates many problems.

From Audacity:

[image]

Are there any known filters/algorithms which can cope with this type of files and make them "normal" ?

Comment: Can you define "normal"?

Comment: @jzd: the waveform must mostly look symetrical and lie around 0 (and not at +1).

Comment: Isn't this caused by wrongly interpreting signed/unsigned values?

Comment: It looks like an ADPCM file wrongly interpreted as a PCM file (in ADPCM, each sample value is stored as the offset from the previous value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound must be heavily distorted.

A possible solution to restore the waveform is to apply a high pass filter at 30hz. If you only care about voice you can then apply a low pass at 10khz to improve the thrashing that the distortion has introduced to the sound.

Note though that there is a possibility that this wav sound has a special encoding. In that case you need to convert or load it correctly instead of trying to fix the sound.